# Fetching next and previous records from database

Tags: mysql, database

When I fetch a specific record from db table, I want to fetch the "previous" and "next" records as well. For example I have a photos table:

```
photo_id    user_id     photo_name      
1             1         xx
2             2          --
3             1          --
4             1          --
```

Now for example, I want to fetch photos of user_id 1. For example if the photo_id is 1, there wont be any previous photo, if photo_id is 3, the previous record will be photo_id 1 and next will be 4.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on `photo_id == 3` and you know that it belongs to `user_id == 1`, then:

the "previous" `photo_id` for that user is:

```
SELECT `photo_id`
  FROM `photos`
 WHERE `photo_id` < 3 AND `user_id` = 1
 ORDER BY `photo_id` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

and the "next" `photo_id` for that user is:

```
SELECT `photo_id`
  FROM `photos`
 WHERE `photo_id` > 3 AND `user_id` = 1
 ORDER BY `photo_id` ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

---

For a bonus point, you can make this more efficient with an index:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_user_photo`
    ON `photos`
       (`user_id`, `photo_id`)
```

Comment: Thanks, about the index, as i want to fetch more columns from photos db, for example photo_name, photo_path etc, will the index same like u mentioned above?

Comment: @sid: That's going into "separate question" territory now I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the previous photo_id like this:

```
SELECT photo_id FROM photos
WHERE user_id = ? AND photo_id < ?
ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

And the next like this:

```
SELECT photo_id FROM photos
WHERE user_id = ? AND photo_id > ?
ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Be sure that you have a composite index on (user_id, photo_id) for better performance. E.g.:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_user_photo ON photos (user_id, photo_id)
```

Comment: Don't forget ordering; MySQL tables have no inherent order, despite what a cursory glance might imply.

Comment: @Tomalak: oops, good point. I updated the answer with ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the required SQL in **just one query** - allows you to fetch all the 3 photos you want at a go (if they exist):

```
SELECT p.`photo_id` AS photo, 
(SELECT o.`photo_id` FROM photos o WHERE o.`user_id` = p.`user_id` AND o.`photo_id` < p.`photo_id` LIMIT 1) AS previous_photo, 
(SELECT o.`photo_id` FROM photos o WHERE o.`user_id` = p.`user_id` AND o.`photo_id` > p.`photo_id` LIMIT 1) AS next_photo 
FROM photos p 
WHERE p.`user_id` = 1 AND p.`photo_id` = 3 LIMIT 1;
```

This will place the current photo (photo_id = 3) in `photo`, place the previous one in `previous_photo` and the next one in `next_photo`.

Hope this helps, Test it and tell me...

Comment: thanks. I'm just curious to know, if using 1 query is better approach or using 3 queries (1 for the specific photo, 2 other queries for previous and next).

Comment: @sid, I think it might be a matter of choice to some, but for me, if I had to execute 3 queries on the db just fetch this data (db i/o is often an expensive operation), then if one query can get me all the data at once, to me this would be better / cheaper. But maybe it depends.